# Generating an array using list values at indices corresponding to entries in a separate list satisfying some criterion

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine one has an array of integer value sets that looks like this:

```
testValues = {{9, 8, 8, 10, 1}, {10, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {8, 0, 0, 5, 7}, {1, 5, 7, 2, 7}, {6, 9, 3, 9, 10}, {7, 10, 7, 5, 3}, {3, 10, 6, 1, 9}, {5, 8, 7, 9, 2}, {2, 3, 2, 7, 0}, {3, 7, 10, 2, 7}};
```

And a set of lists that looks like this:

```
listA = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
listB = {1,2,3,4,5};
listR = {{67,56,55,33,24,32,54,667,99,103498},{5}};
listQ = {{653,29,49,69,19},{20987}}
```

Here, `Length[listA] == Length[listR[[1]]]`, `Length[listB] == Length[listQ[[1]]]`, and the number of entries in `testValues` is `Length[listA]*Length[listB]`.

I want to very quickly output an array with entries:

```
{{listR[[a, 1]], listQ[[b, 1]]},...}
```

For all `{a,b}` pairs where `testValues[[a,b]] >= threshold` for some integer `threshold` value.  The entries in the array do not need to be in any particular order.

The naive way of proceeding could look like:

```
outputList ={};

For[a = 1, a <= Length[listA], a++,
  For[b = 1, b <= Length[listB], b++,

    If[testValues[[a, b]] >= threshold,
      outputList = Append[outputList, {listR[[a, 1]], listQ[[b, 1]]}];
      ];

    ];
  ];
```

However, this is quite slow.  Is there a much faster method using `Select` perhaps?

The relevant list sizes are in reality something like `Length[listA]` $\approx 10^2$, `Length[listB]` $\approx 10^4$, and `testValues` has `Length[listA]*Length[listB]` entries.

---

Update:

I was able to use Position to do the following:

```
goodIndices = Position[int, x_ /; x >= 3];
outputList[[i]] = {listR[[#[[1]], 1]], listQ[[#[[2]], 1]]} & /@ goodIndices;
```

This is about 4x faster than the naive approach I posted earlier.  Are further speedups possible?

Comment: I don't see the definition of listA, listB and listR, listQ.

Comment: In any case, you could play with DeleteCases function with `levelspec` 2

Comment: @VahagnPoghosyan I've added explicit examples for all of the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a straightforward functional transformation of your `For` loop which should be faster:

```
pairs = Select[Tuples[{listA, listB}], Extract[testValues, #] >= threshold &];
outputList = Table[{listR[[First[p], 1]], listQ[[Last[p], 1]]}, {p, pairs}];
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to perform similarly?  I'm getting position specification errors for different examples?

Comment: For your example the code produces the exact same output as your for loop.